# How to append results?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, append

I created a macro using xmlhttp requests to fetch some tabular content from a webpage.
Now I want to append the result to already existing results.

When I run the macro, it writes results in `sheet1` up to row 61.
I want when I rerun the macro, it will write results after row 61 excluding the header and then again after row 121 and so on.

I tried:

```vb
Sub GetTabularContent()
    Const Url = "https://sofifa.com/players?offset=0"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, S$, R&, C&
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim elem As Object, tRow As Object
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With New ServerXMLHTTP
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With
  
    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S

        For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("table")(0).Rows
            For Each tRow In elem.Cells
                C = C + 1: ws.Cells(R + 1, C) = tRow.innerText
            Next tRow
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SETbJ.jpg) is how the result is being written.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to get the last row of Excel and write after it. [This function will do it](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/LastThings.vb):

```
Public Function LastRow(wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

To call the function, try this:

```
dim myLastRow as Long
myLastRow = LastRow(ws.Name)
C = myLastRow
For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("table")(0).Rows
    For Each tRow In elem.Cells
        C = C + 1: ws.Cells(R + 1, C) = tRow.innerText
    Next tRow
    C = myLastRow : R = R + 1
Next elem
```

Give it a few tries, if it does not work exactly as you want it to be, I have not tested it.

Comment: Hi @Vityata, thanks for your answer. Ain't [this](https://filebin.net/8j13u5m54da1gmbv) doing the same thing?

Comment: @SMTH - idk, the best way to find out is to try it, debugging step by step. Just from checking the link I can see that my answer uses `myLastRow` twice and the link uses it once only, thus these cannot be the same.